# SQL Server Cluster Failover -

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on a project that requires a reconfigurement of the current Failover Cluster settings. The project itself requires the availability of a report server as well as the login by use of a windows authenticated account.

The current situation is: Server runs perfect while on the first node, but whenever a failover occurs, and the cluster switches over to the second node, there is an issue with gaining access to the report server. When the cluster is running on the second node, on SSMS the availability group shows that the cluster is in (Secondary) position, while the replicas themselves are as follows: Node1 (secondary), role: Secondary; node2: [blank], role: Unknown.

This also brings up an error saying having issues logging into to the report server from node2.

If anyone knows of anyway, or settings to be changed, I would be greatly appreciative.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm thinking you will reach a better audience for this question on dba.stackexchange.com  (close vote cast to migrate)

Comment: I hope, you are aware of the fact that the SQL Server Reporting Service is not Cluster aware. Have a read of  [`Configuring Reporting Services for Scale-Out Deployment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156453(v=sql.100).aspx) to

Comment: Twelfth: I know, however, experiencing problems creating an account on dba.stackexchange.com

M-Ali: Yes, I am very aware of that. However. I have seen a few ways to work around that, especially using scaled-out deployment. Hoping to find some insight. Thanks for your comments!